# angular-ui-router url gets mistaken for parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm building an application with AngularJS (1.4) and I have a problem with angular-ui-router.

I have this route among others:

```
{
    name: 'personal_payment',
        url: '/:personalLink',
        templateUrl: 'personal_payment/personal_payment.html',
        data: {
            needAuth: false,
            noBackground: true
        }
}
```

and then at the end of the route definitions I have this line of code:

```
states.forEach(function(state) {
    $stateProvider.state(state);
});
```

The problem is that now every page like /login, /dashboard, is mistaken for the :personalLink parameter. With ngRoute it was enough to define first the /login route and then the /:personalLink one, but with angular-ui-router it does not seems to work since the /:personalLink route is the last route of the array.

What am I missing?

EDIT: I noticed that just the /login route does not work, with every other route the resolving order is correct. I guess I have some problem with this particular route!

This is the /login route definition:

```
    {
        name: 'login',
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'login/login.html',
        data: {
            needAuth: false,
            noBackground: false
        }
    },
```

The route does not work even with the controller empty:

```
'use strict';

angular.module(
    'myApp.login', ['ui.router']
).
controller('LoginCtrl', ["$rootScope", function($rootScope) {
}]);
```

the template is the following:

```
<div class='landing1'>
    <div class='landingbox' style='min-height: 386px'>
        <div ng-controller="LoginCtrl" class='below-header'>
            LOGIN PAGE
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="stripebadge">
        <a href='https://herokuapp.com/privacy' target="_blank" class='light-text font-montserrat' style='font-size: 12px; margin-left: 7px'>Privacy Policy</a>
        <a  href="mailto:info@paylinko.com?Subject=Paylinko%20Support%20" class='light-text font-montserrat' style='font-size: 12px; margin-left: 22px;'>Contact</a><br>
        <img src="assets/images/stripebadge.svg" width="185" align="center" style='margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 6px;'><br>
        <span class='light_text' style='font-size: 12px;'>
       <br>
        Copyright &copy; 2016 Paylinko, all rights reserved.</span>
    </div>
    <div ng-include="'footer_pl.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Other routes work fine, I really don't know what's wrong with this one.

Comment: Does it have to be `/:personalLink` or can it be `/endpoint/:personalLink`?

Comment: It would be way better like this compared to adding an endpoint. I won't belive that there is no workaround for this!

Comment: It did not change anything, I updated my question!

Comment: so where is your `/login` route defined? show all route definitions

Comment: I have updated the question!

Comment: @ste, what if you define only one `login` route, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter is the name, so:

```
states.forEach(function(state) {
    $stateProvider.state(state.name, state);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem didn't have anything to do with the route system. Basically the problem was when a route link (Eg: '/login') matched a physical folder inside the application architecture. All the route that were working had different name compared to the folder that contained the files (Eg: the route name is '/account' but the folder name is 'setting').

I added this code in my server file:

```
app.use('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.baseUrl && (req.baseUrl.match(/\.*\.(js|html|css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|ico|php|xml|txt)\.*/g) )) {
            return next();
        } else {
            res.sendfile('app/index.html');
        }

});
```

Now everything works fine.